# React.js conditional render if search dropdown has any element

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React and trying to do simple search form with dropdown. When you enter any word in the `input`, `render()` makes the `list` depending of prop `name`. So, I want to make a conditional render with `drop` - if there is nothing in `list`, it would render nothing. I tried to do this by checking `list` length, but it is always 5.
P.S. in adition, how do I ignore case of `input` value by using `includes()` function?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FoundedIngridient from './FoundedIngridient';

export default class FoundedIngridients extends Component {
    ingridients = [
        {
            img: 'https://k-f.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/karl-1.2.png',
            name: 'Martini'
        },
        {
            img: 'https://k-f.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/karl-1.2.png',
            name: 'Beer'
        },
        {
            img: 'https://k-f.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/karl-1.2.png',
            name: 'Jim Beem'
        },
        {
            img: 'https://k-f.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/karl-1.2.png',
            name: 'Jack Daniels'
        },
        {
            img: 'https://k-f.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/karl-1.2.png',
            name: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, molestiae tempora iste suscipit incidunt aliquid?'
        },
    ]

    state = {
        searchVal: '',
        isDropShown: false
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            searchVal: e.target.value,
            isDropShown: e.target.value == '' ? false : true
        });
    }

    render() {
        const list = this.ingridients.map((ingridient, key) => {
            return (
                ingridient.name.includes(this.state.searchVal.toString()) &&
                <FoundedIngridient
                    key={`drop-${key}`}
                    img={ingridient.img}
                    name={ingridient.name}
                >
                </FoundedIngridient>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className="form">
                <form action="#">
                    <div className="input-wraper">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="For example, beer.."
                            value={this.state.searchVal}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {
                        (
                            this.state.isDropShown &&
                            list.length
                        ) &&
                        <div className="drop">
                            <div className="block">
                                {list}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and so far it's working fine, it renders nothing when the input value is empty string, what else do you want?

Comment: The code is correct. just to ignore case sensitivity: `ingridient.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchVal.toString().toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example of how to implement a list with filter. See on the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-worker-jv09y).

In your example React doesn't track the list instance, therefore you have 5 as result. You need to move this array to the store and use it in render function.